# Window messages v/s COM connection point

Tags: winapi, com

I would like to communicate between two processes running on the same machine.
I don not have luxury to use any sort of general IPC(e.g. shared memory, pipe, sockets etc.)

I can able to use window messages to communicate between both the process.

please advice will it be faster to use COM connection point rather than window messages.

Is COM connection point also based on window message queue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Ashish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> please advice will it be faster to use COM connection point rather
>   than window messages.

It largely depends on how you use Windows messages to communicate between processes.
For simple cases like calling a COM method without arguments, a synchronous inter-process call will **not** be faster than using `SendMessage` directly, because of the reason explained below.

> Is COM connection point also based on window message queue.

It is not based on window message queue. COM connection point is just a convention for implementing outgoing COM interfaces. However, the COM inter-process marshaller does indeed use hidden windows and private messages to marshal calls, when it comes to making an out-of-proc call on a connection point interface.

This is not specific to connection points and applies to any COM proxy interface you may have cached. Normally, you need to have a functional message loop inside both client and server processes for this to work properly.